# .3ds with JOGL?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I would like to use .3ds models with JOGL. How can I do this? How can I import other file formats, like .max or .obj?

Thanks. I'm new to OpenGL and JOGL.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find the plain Javadoc (or a clean library download) for it anywhere but [`ModelFactory.createModel(...)`](http://projectkenai.com/projects/jogl/sources/jogl-utils-git/content/src/net/java/joglutils/model/ModelFactory.java) in [JOGLUtils](http://projectkenai.com/projects/jogl/sources/jogl-utils-git/show) will load some .3ds files.

**Edit:** DURP I forgot: You can render them with [`DisplayListRenderer`](http://projectkenai.com/projects/jogl/sources/jogl-utils-git/content/src/net/java/joglutils/model/examples/DisplayListRenderer.java) which is also in JOGLUtils.